# Uploading for to internet site

Tags: go

With the below code I can download a file from internet asking with monitoring the downloaded percentage.

How can I do something to upload file to internet as well as monitoring the upload progress. I want to upload executable file at github assets

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/dustin/go-humanize"
)

// WriteCounter counts the number of bytes written to it. It implements to the io.Writer interface
// and we can pass this into io.TeeReader() which will report progress on each write cycle.
type WriteCounter struct {
    Total uint64
}

func (wc *WriteCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n := len(p)
    wc.Total += uint64(n)
    wc.PrintProgress()
    return n, nil
}

func (wc WriteCounter) PrintProgress() {
    // Clear the line by using a character return to go back to the start and remove
    // the remaining characters by filling it with spaces
    fmt.Printf("\r%s", strings.Repeat(" ", 35))

    // Return again and print current status of download
    // We use the humanize package to print the bytes in a meaningful way (e.g. 10 MB)
    fmt.Printf("\rDownloading... %s complete", humanize.Bytes(wc.Total))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Download Started")

    fileUrl := "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/Wp-w4-big.jpg"
    err := DownloadFile("avatar.jpg", fileUrl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Download Finished")
}

// DownloadFile will download a url to a local file. It's efficient because it will
// write as it downloads and not load the whole file into memory. We pass an io.TeeReader
// into Copy() to report progress on the download.
func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    // Create the file, but give it a tmp file extension, this means we won't overwrite a
    // file until it's downloaded, but we'll remove the tmp extension once downloaded.
    out, err := os.Create(filepath + ".tmp")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Get the data
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        out.Close()
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Create our progress reporter and pass it to be used alongside our writer
    counter := &WriteCounter{}
    if _, err = io.Copy(out, io.TeeReader(resp.Body, counter)); err != nil {
        out.Close()
        return err
    }

    // The progress use the same line so print a new line once it's finished downloading
    fmt.Print("\n")

    // Close the file without defer so it can happen before Rename()
    out.Close()

    if err = os.Rename(filepath+".tmp", filepath); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Why doesn’t the same strategy work for uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modify your code. It works for my file server.

```
func UploadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    // Create the file, but give it a tmp file extension, this means we won't overwrite a
    // file until it's downloaded, but we'll remove the tmp extension once downloaded.
    out, err := os.Open(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create our progress reporter and pass it to be used alongside our writer
    counter := &WriteCounter{}

    // Get the data
    resp, err := http.Post(url, "multipart/form-data", io.TeeReader(out, counter))
    if err != nil {
        out.Close()
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // The progress use the same line so print a new line once it's finished downloading
    fmt.Print("\n")

    // Close the file without defer so it can happen before Rename()
    out.Close()

    return nil
}
```